# Simple image gallery cannot write to cache folder even with permission set to 777

Tags: joomla, ftp, file-writing, folder-permissions

I am using a joomla plugin that shows multiple images inside a gallery. But whenever I add the code for the plugin inside an article I get this error:

```
Simple Image Gallery Notice: Joomla!'s /cache folder is not writable. Please correct this folder's permissions, clear your site's cache and retry.
```

So I connected to my website with FTP and changed the permissions of the cache folder located at administrator/cache to 777 (Permission for everything), but I keep getting this message.

What could be the cause of this? And is there a work-around?

Comment: Some hosts don't like people using 777, try 775 or 755 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has a cache folder directly in the joomla root. You have to set the permissions of this folder (e.g. /var/www/joomla/cache), but it looks like you set them of /var/www/joomla/administrator/cache.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the case, I already figured it out. I did not even have a cache folder in the joomla root so I added one. Now I don't get the error anymore but the plugin still doesn't work as needed. That's for another stackoverflow post though.

Comment: Also check out [this article](https://docs.joomla.org/Verifying_permissions), joomla doesn't recommend to use 0777.

Comment: Joomla is reading my cache file with its permissions set to 755 so that's not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using centos, you can change selinux to permissive mode. It works.